# Need to remove the unwanted space content elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having the space in  element, because of that space, I'm getting validation error.

My Input xml:

```
<div><a href="https://tneb.com"><img src="https://tnee.com"/></a>
<div> </div>
</div>
```

XSL I used:

```
<xsl:template match="div">
<fig>
<xsl:apply-templates/>    
</fig>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
<xsl:element name="xref">
<xsl:if test="@href">
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="img">
<xsl:element name="image">
<xsl:if test="@src">
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Output I'm getting as:

```
<fig>
<xref href="https://tneb.com">
<image href="https://tnee.com"/>
</xref> </fig>
```

But I need the expected output be like:

```
<fig>
<xref href="https://tneb.com">
<image href="https://tnee.com"/>
</xref></fig>
```

Because of that unwanted , I'm getting space in between the tags. So I getting validation error. Please provide me the coding for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/6rewNyX does not produce the output you say you get so I am not sure what you want to achieve. What are the rules for eliminating spaces, which output format is that that doesn't validate?

Comment: @MartinHonnen the space between the </xref> </fig> raising the validation error. because of the unwanted space inside <div>. That your link specified in comment showing error. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from a correction in your XSLT: You wrote:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:attribute>
```

and it should be changed to:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@src"/></xsl:attribute>
```

And now back to your question: Put

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

at the beginning of your XSLT (just after `xsl:stylesheet`).

Then:

- due to `indent="yes"` you will get a pretty formatted output,
- due to `strip-space` instead of `<fig> </fig>` you will get `<fig/>`.